# Cannot search mongo db by timestamp

Tags: mongodb

Hey I am having an issue with this line of code

```
 db.eventrecords.find({ timestamp: { $gte:ISODate("2013-11-19T14:00:00Z"), 
 $lt: ISODate("2018-11-19T20:00:00Z") } })
```

This query and any similiar query using timestamp returns nothing even though I know there is data there.

Here is an example of that data returned with d.eventrecords.find()

```
 { "_id" : ObjectId("5a0c9e22da6e704174881b6c"), "userId" : 
  "59e0265c387d7d22a4f81533", "timestamp" : "Wed Nov 15 2017 15:05:54 GMT-
   0500 (Eastern Standard Time)", "name" : "LOGIN" }
```

Can anyone shed light on why this query won't return data?

Comment: Your timestamp is a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that because you store dates as string (not timestamp).